# Logic form of the existence of inverse

Tags: field-theory, definition, logic-translation

I was studying calculus and while reading the axioms of a field I was trying to write them all only using logic notation. Although, I’m not quite confident if the following statement

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{K} \, , \, \exists y,z \in \mathbb{K} \, \colon \; [\, ( \neg [\, \forall w \in \mathbb{K} \, , \; x + w = w \,] \implies x \cdot y = z ) \, \wedge \, ( \forall a \in \mathbb{K} \, , \; [\, \neg (\forall b \in \mathbb{K} \, , \; z + b = b ) \, \wedge \, ( \neg [\, \forall c \in \mathbb{K} \, , \; a + c = c \,] \implies z \cdot a = a ) \,] ) \,]$$

correctly states the existence of a inverse element for every non-zero element. Can you give me some feedback? Thank you for your attention!

**Note.** I wish to avoid the use of symbol $0$ for the identity for addition.

Comment: @Math3147 I want to try to avoid the symbol $0$. Also, note that this is not a proof, because, as you said, they’re axioms. This is just an exercise of writing in logical notation

Comment: Solution should be fixed now, without $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 1):

In the first-order form of fields, we say that for ($\mathbf{F}$, +, $\cdot$, $0$ , $1$) where $0 \neq 1$, that the inverse axiom under multiplication is $$\forall x \; \exists y \; (y \cdot x = 1 \; \leftrightarrow \; x \neq 0)$$
Under addition
$$\forall x \; \exists y \; (x + y = 0)$$
You don't need to prove the statements as they're *axioms*, because it seems like you're going for a proof there. If you don't want to put the $0$ like you said in the comments, then say
$$\forall x \;\exists y \; (y \cdot x = 1 \; \leftrightarrow \; \forall z \; (z + x \neq z))$$

I hope this answers your question. :)

*Edit*:
I'm going to critique your formalization too as requested at the end.
First, I'm going to put it into Prenex so it is easily read:
$$\forall x \; \exists z \; \Bigg(\Big(\forall w \;\lnot (x + w = w) \to \exists y \; (x \cdot y = z)\Big) \; \land \; \big(\forall b \; \lnot (z + b = b)\big) \; \land \; \bigg(\forall a \Big(\; \forall c \; \lnot (a + c = c) \; \to \;  (z \cdot a = a)\Big)\bigg) \Bigg)$$
Now, this is saying that if not all elements are identity elements then there is an identity element $z$, and it is not an additive element, and also that it is the multiplicative identity. Now, I see this as redundant as the symbol $z$ here acts like the symbol $1$ (replace every $z$ with $1$, and you'll see what I mean) so, you've reached the same conclusion, and it won't be exactly the same as $z$ is not constant now but merely has the same properties. A constant is different from a variable in first-order logic, and so it is stated without a quantifier. Also that, even if we would ignore all of the listed problems, assume that the left-hand side of each implication is false, then the implication is still true, and therefore it could be an identity element at the same time (if not for the middle-clause between the conjunction). I suggest putting it like this (to ensure they're both distinct)
$$\forall x \; \exists y \; \exists b \; \big((x + y = x) \; \land \; \forall a \; (a \cdot b = a) \; \leftrightarrow \; y \neq b \big)$$
If not wanted, then remove the left-hand side of each implication (and the implication itself while leaving the right side), and it would say the same thing. I.e.
$$\forall x \; \exists z \; (\exists y \; (x \cdot y = z) \; \land \; (x + z \neq x) \; \land \; (x \cdot z = x))$$

Comment: I think there is something wrong, how can it be $y \cdot x = x$?

Comment: Fixed it, and tried to address what you wrote. @MathPapers

Comment: I used $z$ to replace $1$ because so far I don’t know if the identity elements (for addition and multiplication) are unique [I know that they are unique, but while stating the axioms we can’t take it for guaranteed]. I didn’t quite understood the discussion of having another identity element if the antecedent of the implications are false. Can you elaborate it?

Comment: If $\bot \to \top$ then it is still true. Meaning in a truth able, even if the antecedent is false, the implication is still true so long as the consequent (rght-hand side) is true. They're unique as $1$ and $0$ are distinct. @MathPapers

Comment: Also, while stating it in the axioms you en fact can. That is the purpose of an axiom, to allow you to construct things with guarantee except for when they generate inconsistencies.